# What is wrong with .net dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

Without any words:

```
public class MemoryDictionary<T>
{
    private Dictionary<T, T> items = new Dictionary<T, T>();
    public T GetValue<T>(T value)
    {
        if (!items.ContainsKey(value))
        {
            items[value] = value;

        }
        return items[value];
    }
}
```

What is wrong here, and why doesn't it compile? I mean, it's actually saying that `ContainsKey` method has an invalid argument, but....it is stupid! The argument is correct!

And what is strange:

```
public class MemoryDictionary<string>
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> items = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    public string GetValue<string>(string value)
    {
        if (!items.ContainsKey(value))
        {
            items[value] = value;

        }
        return items[value];
    }
}
```

This code and any code where i chose some specific type is compiling well... I'm stunned...

Comment: What is the exact compilation error you are getting?

Comment: The code that you say compiles is full of multiple compiler errors...

Comment: As a side note, any time you think that the C# language or one of the .NET classes has a bug in it, you can be virtually certain that the bug is with your usage of it instead.  The odds of it being the language or base library with a bug is...small.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that you've defined `T` twice.  You've made both the class and the method generic, and given both of them a generic argument with the same name.

Your field is defined outside the method, and as such `T` in that context only refers to the `T` declared as the class' generic argument.

The parameter `value` is declared in a location where the method's generic argument is in scope, and since that method's `T` is "closer" than the `T` declared at the class level, it "wins" when trying to resolve the type of that variable.

So now you have a parameter of type `T`, and a `Dicitonary<T, T>`, and yet *the type of that parameter is still different from the generic arguments of the dictionary*.

And easy way to make this clear would be to go to either generic argument and use visual studio's "rename" feature to rename the type (to just `T2` or something) and you'll see which `T`'s change and which don't.  After doing this the error message will also make sense as these different types will actually be displayed differently in the error message.

As for a fix, just make the method not be generic.

Answer (score 3):

You have a naming conflict between generic type constraint in the class and the `GetValue()` method.

Removing the type constraint on the method should solve the problem:

```
public T GetValue(T value)
```